# Python sockets and split function

Tags: python, sockets, split

I am new with Python and I need to do a program with sockets. 
My server needs to send data with sockets to a client. It simple gives a name of a file
and his size.

So, I send the data in the following format, using the TCP Server class:

```
for fname, size in db.getfiles():
  temp = fname + " " + size + " "
  buffer = buffer + temp

self.request.send(buffer)
```

So I have a long string to send.

I receive it in the Client, and I want to use:

```
 List = data.split(" ")
```

But I want to use List like a parallel array where I can print the name and the file in one loop, I want:

```
 for name, f_size in List:
      print name, f_name
```

How I can do this? If I can't do this within the same List, How I split again the list so I can print in this way?

If this cannot be done, how I can jump every two index in the List so that I can print both things at the same time?

For example:

```
 for i in List:
     print i, i + 1
     #jump now to index 2
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should [serialize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) your list when sending it over the network, and unserialize it on the other end.  So, something like this on the sending side:

```
import pickle

list = db.getfiles()
self.request.send(pickle.dumps(list))
```

And on the receiving side:

```
import pickle
List = pickle.loads(data)
```

Serialization transforms your data structure into a format suitable for transmission or storage, and unserialization transforms the encoded data back into the original data structure.  Doing it this way, you start with a list of tuples on the sender (assuming that this is what you get from `db.getfiles()`) and you end up with a list of tuples on the receiver.

The `pickle` module isn't the only mechanism available for serialization.  Other common serialization formats include JSON (via the `json` module), YAML, and XML.

Comment: from the db.getfiles() I get: FILE, that are all the saved files in the database and SIZE, that is the size of each file in the database. Did you know a way that usign split do waht I want? Is just that I done understand exactly what you say about serialization... :/

Comment: Yeah, you're not understand this answer.  Take some time to read the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) that I linked to.  This is really what you want to do, rather than mucking about with delimiters and whatnot, because it's a general technique that can be used in a variety of situations with data structures that are more complex than what you're currently using.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble with your current message format is that you're using the same delimiter between your two data values (`fname` and `size`) and between separate items of data (that is, the name and size of different files). While it's possible to grab the values in pairs, it requires a bit more effort than I think is necessary. Instead, I suggest using two different delimiters.

For instance, you could send each file's information on a separate line by putting a newline character (`"\n"`) after the size, instead of the space you're currently putting. Then on the reading end, you'll want to two two `split` operations, resulting in a list of lists:

```
raw_data = some_socket_read_function()
data = [line.split(" ") for line in raw_data.split("\n")]

for fname, size in data: # you can unpack the two values directly while iterating
    do_stuff(fname, size)
```

If you don't want to use newlines, there are all sorts of other characters you could use (commas, colons, etc.) to distinguish between the two kinds of separations you have in your data.

Answer (score 0):

The other two answers are correct that it would be cleaner to send your data in another format. However, if for some reason you can't change the format of the data you're receiving, you could do this

```
List = data.split(" ")
List = zip(List[::2], List[1::2])

for name, size in List:
  # do something with name and size
```

The `zip` function makes a list of pairs, forming each pair from corresponding elements in the two lists. So `zip([1,2,3], [4,5,6])` returns `[(1,4), (2,5), (3,6)]`. `List[::2]` returns every second element in `List`, starting at element 0, and `List[1::2]` returns every second element in `List` starting at element 1.